# Did the computing power of end users increase at a steady pace over the years?

Tags: history, performance

Does the computing power of the average people in the household increase at a steady pace or has it wax and waned over the years? Are there some eras of computers where computing power grew faster than others or has it been a steady increase in power since personal computers became a thing?

EDIT:

I'm interested in home computing, in the US. Computers that were generally accessible and not overly expensive. Just generally how has the average person's computer power increased over the course of the computer revolution? Was it a steady increase or did the increase vary?

Comment: Sadly, my personal computing power seems to be in decline, particularly with respect to memory. More and more of it seems to be SE-RAM, sleep-erasable...

Comment: Which country (or countries) are you interested in? Are you looking for facts and figures? Anecdotally, I’d say it progressed in fits and starts — from one computer per household (of varying power), with an increasing number of equipped households (driven more by consoles than computers), to several computers (including consoles) per household, to multiple computers per person (counting phones, tablets, laptops, TV “casting” devices, SBCs etc.)...

Comment: OK, let's use US households for the sake of this argument

Comment: Also, which computers count? Do embedded controllers count?

Comment: No personal computers / hobby machines

Comment: When you meet the average man, you have to remember that 50% of the population are less intelligent...

Comment: I have made an edit in an attempt to keep this question from getting closed.

Comment: Are you wanting to check out Moore's Law?

Comment: @SolarMike - that is one component. Now between phones, laptops, and tablets everyone in my household has multiple compute devices versus one initially...

Comment: If anything, it seems that today's devices are practically dumb terminals for the web -- with most of the computing power now in the cloud -- and that the climax of the average person's computing power was maybe 15-20 years ago.

Comment: @NeilMeyer So is a C64 professional or home computer? Or what about an Apple II? Keep in mind, that's the machine Visicalc was made for. Professional and home are terms of usage, not devices, similar doe home at best define where a machine is located, not what power it offers  - which in turn doesn't really say something about it's usability, considering ho much power is wasted to push a mouse around the screen.

Comment: I learned how to program in 1962.  Households didn't have computers in those days.  If you start from zero, how do you measure percentage increase?  ;)

Comment: @WalterMitty - my parents were cheapskates, they wouldn't spend a few hundreds of thousands of pounds to buy me a computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personal and home computers have improved with computer technology in general over the last 40 years or so.  Over the period of 1990 to 2005, the technology underlying personal computers, particularly the family that started as "IBM PC compatible", became the main platform for all computing.  Most servers and even supercomputers over the last couple decades are derived from that platform.  And you can generally buy the same underlying hardware in a desktop form factor, at the premium end of personal computers.  (Whether this will remain true for much longer is unclear.  Tablets and smartphones may be an upset just as PCs were to the minicomputers that came before them.)

There have been periods when the cost-per-performance increase has stalled.  For example, there are several periods of DRAM shortage historically which briefly flattened the otherwise downward trend in $ per kilo/mega/giga/terabyte of DRAM.  But as a general rule, personal computers have gotten faster, more efficient and cheaper, continuously since shortly after their introduction.

Comment: Definitely agree with your outlook on the future.  It seems that computing power is increasingly being moved into the cloud, with personal devices now essentially fancy terminals.  Long battery life for personal devices is now more of a priority than their performance.

Comment: There is orders of magnitude difference between the available computer power in an average household and what is actually used. Most of DrSheldons "fancy terminals" have far more CPU and RAM than a 1980s supercomputer. But if use use terminally inefficient software, you probably need all that computing resource to watch a cat video.

Comment: While there is a trend to use more 'off shore' power, even comparable 'dumb' devices used to access external resources continues to increase in power. So not really changing the trend.